# Is it accessible to use SVG in IMG tag?

Tags: html, image, svg, accessibility

I have an SVG image that I am going to use on my website like this

```
<img src="test.svg" alt="This is a test alt" />
```

The question I have, is using .SVG with IMG selector and 'alt' tag OK/good for accessibility?

Comment: what do you mean by accessibility?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) SVG is a valid type to use for image sources. Don't see why it would be a problem.

Comment: @MartinMeli Screen readers

Comment: Official spec here for accessible svgs: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/access.html#SVGAccessibilityGuidelines and an article here: https://webaim.org/blog/future-web-accessibility-svg/ and here W3C Editor's Draft: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/access.html#SVGRelatedAccessibilityDocuments

Comment: Hi @NathanielFlick, if you add your comment as answer I will accept as it helped me

Comment: Hi @js-learner thanks will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes SVGs in an image tag are accessible with an alt. I have also seen an aria-label used but this is probably not necessary. You can also use SVGs natively (without the img tag) follow these specifications:

- Official spec here for accessible svgs:
  [w3.org/TR/SVG11/access.html#SVGAccessibilityGuidelines](https://w3.org/TR/SVG11/access.html#SVGAccessibilityGuidelines)
- and an article here on WebAim for the Future of SVG accessibility: [webaim.org/blog/future-web-accessibility-svg](https://webaim.org/blog/future-web-accessibility-svg)
- and here the W3C Editor's Draft (meaning it's not yet complete): [w3.org/TR/SVG/access.html#SVGRelatedAccessibilityDocuments](https://w3.org/TR/SVG/access.html#SVGRelatedAccessibilityDocuments)

Make sure to test with the [SiteImprove Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/siteimprove-browser-exten/amoojkmllfodlpgmdnclkgdnejgpeada) and whichever screenreader you have access to, JAWS, NVDA or VoiceOver. If the svg is properly read, then chances are it's passed Accessibility.

Comment: that webAIM article is interesting, although pretty old! I've used SVG and JS to create interactive accessible graphics, you can add `tabindex` attributes to individual SVG sub elements e.g. `<g id="test" tabindex=0 aria-label="hullo world">...</g>` - most of aria is available too. It works pretty well across browsers apart from IE. But even IE can be made to work if required, by using xlink

Comment: The other excellent extension to check accessibility is https://www.deque.com/axe

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter the format (as long it is a [valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) one), it does matter the tag you use (`img`) and its attributes in this case the `alt` which has to be descriptive of the image user is seeing

And because you have a `svg` format, you can also use `svg` inline as long you follow the [accessibility guidelines from W3C.](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/access.html#SVGAccessibilityGuidelines)

> Provide text equivalents for graphics.
>
> - When the text content of a graphic (e.g., in a ‘text’ element) explains its function, no text equivalent is required. Use the ‘title’
>   child element to explain the function of ‘text’ elements whose meaning
>   is not clear from their text content.
> - When a graphic does not include explanatory text content, it requires a text equivalent. If the equivalent is complex, use the
>   ‘desc’ element, otherwise use the ‘title’ child element.
> - If a graphic is built from meaningful parts, build the description from meaningful parts.

Answer (score 1):

your example is fine, a screen reader can use the alt property to describe the image

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is! But first I think we need to have a clear idea of what an image really is. Image is a graphical/visual representation of something. It could be a figure or art. Now there's numerous ways to display an image. But When it comes to format(JPG, PNG, GIF OR SVG),it is the method of how the image is is processed + stored and many other functionality. Once an image is displayed, the only thing that matters to common users, is the content.  "alt" is an accessibility attribute, which describes the content of the image. So there should be no relation with "alt" attribute with the format of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use it in REACT as img tag whatever solution I used. And as a object it would mess up the styling. The solution I came up with was to create a new TSX file that returns a svg html. In this way, I can call it wherever I'm in need of it. So something like this:
[image: REACT SVG Component]

And then use it like this in your component. And that's all:
[image: Usage of REACT SVG Component]